# Rails - Associate three Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

Having three models: Datum, Author, and Book .

```
class Datum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authors
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :datum
 has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end
```

For exercise purpose, I wanted to model it that Datum(more general), can have many authors, which can have books.
After creating a datum object and an associated author for it, I could call nameofdatum.authors, but if I added a book to that author, it could not be recognized through nameofdatum.authors.books. Am I having wrong expectations ?  (Should this be done with 'through'(an explanation of it would be much appreciated)

(Schema here if needed)

```
 create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "age"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "book_id"
    t.integer "datum_id"
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_authors_on_book_id"
    t.index ["datum_id"], name: "index_authors_on_datum_id"
  end



 create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "book_type"
    t.integer "pages"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_books_on_author_id"
  end



create_table "data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "region"
    t.integer "budget"
    t.date "aval"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this be done with 'through'?

Yes, `Datum` `has_many` `books` through the `authors` assocition:

```
class Datum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authors
  has_many :books, through: :authors
end
```

And the `books` can be selected via:

```
Datum.last.books
```

It's actually selects `books` using the following query:

```
SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "books"."author_id" WHERE "authors"."datum_id" = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new book through author, you have to assign an author. So you can try:
`nameofdatum.author.books.build ...`.

your code`nameofdatum.authors.books`, you can't use a plural(author) to add a new book.
Hope to help you.